# How to set a tableView Cell Identifier in a UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

### Who do to set a tableView Cell Identifier in a UIViewController ?

Using `UITableViewController` I always do it through the interface (see screenshot below)

[image]

Now I dont see that option if I use `UIViewController`

here's my code

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    NSString *messageAtIndexPath = [messageArray objectAtIndex :[indexPath row]];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:messageAtIndexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

please advice

Unless I add a prototype cell which messes my interface.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things here:

1)  A UITableViewController *inherits* from UIViewController (which I think is what you are actually talking about, instead of "UIControllerView").  UITableViewControllers have the ability to do prototype cells and set these identifiers...

2) ... which are ***case sensitive***.  In your screenshot, you call it "`cell`" while in your code you call it "`Cell`".

They need to be spelled exactly the same and in the same upper/lower case way.

It's not super clear what you are trying to do here, but I sense that you want to create a custom cell in your XIB or storyboard and then reference it in your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`" method. [Here is a tutorial that talks about prototype cells and identifiers and using them in storyboards](http://www.colejoplin.com/2012/09/28/ios-tutorial-basics-of-table-views-and-prototype-cells-in-storyboards/), and I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, I meant `UIViewController` , I dont see where to set the Identifier in the attribute inspector. The link you provided use `UITableViewController`

Comment: You can't set a table view cell identifier in a UIViewController's inspector since UIViewController knows nothing about a table view cell. That's why I suggested the tutorial, if you don't want to use a UITableViewController but instead get your table into a UIViewController you can drop prototype cells into a table view which you've put into a regular UIViewController.  You have a few options here.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, when I drag and drop it, it puts a large gap on top of the tableview. how can I fix it. I want to use `UIViewController` because `UITableViewController` wont let me add more controlls. I put a screenshot to my post. Xcode is not letting me reduce the gap

Comment: The prototype cell goes in the middle of the interface in Interface Builder, but I suspect it will look better when you run the app in your simulator.

Comment: Thanks michael for the help